# Postgis Tiger Geocoder returning null results

Tags: postgresql, postgis, geocoding, geocode, tiger-lines

I have loaded tiger data into my postgres database.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM tiger_data.county_all;

count-> 3233

SELECT count(*) FROM tiger_data.state_all;

count-> 56
```

Extensions are working

```
SELECT na.address,
       na.streetname,na.streettypeabbrev,
       na.zip
FROM normalize_address('1 Devonshire Place, Boston, MA 02109') AS na;
```

returns

```
address | streetname | streettypeabbrev |  zip
---------+------------+------------------+-------
   1 | Devonshire | Pl               | 02109
```

Search path to the database is also set

```
ALTER DATABASE geocoder
    SET search_path TO '"$user", public, tiger';
```

But when I run a query to search something I get **null** results.

```
SELECT g.rating,
       ST_AsText(ST_SnapToGrid(g.geomout,0.00001)) As wktlonlat,
       (addy).address As stno, (addy).streetname As street,
       (addy).streettypeabbrev As styp, (addy).location As city, 
       (addy).stateabbrev As st,(addy).zip
FROM geocode('424 3rd St, Davis, CA 95616',1) As g;
```

returns **nothing**

I followed this tutorial
[How to make a PostGIS TIGER Geocoder in Less than 5 Days](https://experimentalcraft.wordpress.com/2017/11/01/how-to-make-a-postgis-tiger-geocoder-in-less-than-5-days/)
But I still can't get it to work.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Simple mistake. I had not loaded the state data.

Here is a code to generate a script to load California data.

```
psql -U postgres -c "SELECT Loader_Generate_Script(ARRAY['CA'], 'sh')" -d bulk_geocoder -tA > ca_script_load.sh
```

Then run the script ca_script_load.sh after making changes to pg details.

```
bash ca_script_load.sh
```

This will fetch data for the state of california and then load the databse.

Follow this tutorial. **State loading is from** **point 12**

[2.8.1. Tiger Geocoder Enabling your PostGIS database: Using Extension](http://postgis.net/docs/postgis_installation.html#loading_extras_tiger_geocoder)